# Amazon S3 Поиск по маске имени PHP Api

Tags: php, amazon, amazon-web-services

Подскажите, кто знает как можно найти файл в сервисе Amazon S3 используя `API for PHP`. Есть некая структура со вложенными каталогами, по документации самого `API` можно получить список файлов каталога используя параметр `Prefix` как путь к каталогу. Но есть ли возможность уже в рамках каталога искать по шаблону имени, например `file-?-name`, где знак вопроса как любой символ? И такой же вопрос по поиску папок, например `catalog/image/?/main`, что означает выбрать список файлов из всех подкаталогов каталога `image` и в каждом подкаталоге получить список файлов из каталога `main`?

UPD: Есть просьба привести код, в принципе там код по работе с API как есть

```
$bucket = 'aws_bucket';
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
    'region' => 'aws_region',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'aws_key',
        'secret' => 'aws_secret',
    ]
));


$file_list = $s3->listObjects(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'uploads/images/100-',
));
```

Вот так по документации возвращается список файлов из каталога /images у которых имя начинается на "100-", но нужно например получить список файлов по маске "100-?-foro.jpg" что бы в перечень попали файлы с именем:
"100-quality-foto.jpg, 100-quality1-foro.jpg" но не попадали файлы с именем "100-quality-foto1.jpg" или "100-quality-foto.png", т.е. файлы с другой правой частью названия или другим расширением. на сколько я понимаю в частном порядке можно применять вместе с Prefix ещё Suffix в котором определять окончание строки но это не решает проблемы с поиском в нескольких каталогах или по сложной маске файла типа "100-?-foto.?".

Comment: Приведите пример кода и тогда Вам постараются помочь.

Comment: `array_filter($file_list, $item => preg_match($item, $pattern));`

Comment: @Etki Интересный способ, не подумал с этой стороны, подразумевается работа с массивом файлов уже полученным с сервера, если для решения вопроса не найдется способа с забором нужного списка сразу с корзины то прийдется использовать этот вариант. У этого способа есть один недостаток, исходя из ограничений API в ответе может быть не более 1000 записей(файлов), в принципе пока большого кол-ва файлов не используется но в будущем все может быть.